# zf2 access url parameters in controller, form and view

Tags: zend-framework2, multilingual

I am working on a multi-lingual website in ZF2. For same I need to pass the "locale" and "textDomain to "translate" and "url" helper in controller/form/views.

How best I can retrieve and pass it across MVC. I am not able to conclude on how to handle form label translation.

Thanks in advance for help/suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

check out the docs:

https://packages.zendframework.com/docs/latest/manual/en/modules/zend.form.view.helpers.html

If you have a Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator attached, FormLabel view helper will translate the label contents during it's rendering.

```
// Setting a translator
$this->formLabel()->setTranslator($translator);

// Setting a text domain
$this->formLabel()->setTranslatorTextDomain('my-text-domain');

// Setting both
$this->formLabel()->setTranslator($translator, 'my-text-domain');
```

Note

Note: If you have a translator in the Service Manager under the key, ‘translator’, the view helper plugin manager will automatically attach the translator to the FormLabel view helper. See Zend\View\HelperPluginManager::injectTranslator() for more information.

The ZF2 skeleton application shows you howto setup a translator as above, which will automatically translate the labels for you :)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am adding my AlbumForm code. Please advice where shall I make the necessary change. Thnx and Regards